# What is attacking my morning glories and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: plant-health, pests, growth, morning-glory

[image][image][image][image][image]enter image description here[image]
What is this affecting my morning glories? And what can I do to help get rid of it? 
I have took a wet napkin and wiped them off today. I also have seen small bugs crawling around the top soil.

[image]

[image]

These are the bugs that are in my morning glories I don’t know what they are. Could these be what’s leaving the white stuff on back of leaves? The white stuff also has black specs in the middle of it. Please help. 
When I shake plant you can see the white stuff falling off. But the majority of the white stuff stays on.

Comment: We need to see a picture of the bugs. Can you describe the white stuff better

Comment: Hi, I can try to get a picture of them. But they are very very small. But I will do my best. Thanks for replying back

Comment: @user33232 hi, just figured out how to reply the correct way. I was able to take a picture but it’s came up as a new post. How do I post a pic in this? To. E they are so small it’s hard to get a good picture of them. They remind me of little tiny tiny flies or spider looking th8ngs

Comment: @user33232 I hope the other pic helps a bit better

Answer (score 3):

You have *[wooly aphids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eriosomatinae)*, a kind of aphids that grow a waxy, fluffy, wooly protective “fur”. The crawling insects might be adults, but without pictures, a definitive id is nearly impossible.

Treatment options are manual removal, predatory insects (either from your environment or bought), neem oil, insecticidal soap, chemical sprays or systemic insecticides. For a small colony like yours, simply wiping them off is a good start and might suffice, but in most cases, repeat treatments will be necessary.

Comment: @Stephanie I just figured out hot to respond to you, do you know how I can post a picture so you can see it? Thanks

Comment: @MichelleOliveira you can edit your original post. If you click on the photo icon, the menu should guide you through the process.

Comment: @MichelleOliveira edited the question for you. You could delete the other post.

Comment: @Stephanie I’m showing both pics now. I know it’s hard to see them but they are so tiny I can’t get a good pic. Sorry.